# Checking Membership in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

In Python 3 it is working

```
a=["Abhi", "Gupta"]
eval(input("Please enter a string: ")) in a
Please enter a string:  "Abhi"
=> True
```

But in Python 2 I am getting following error

```
a=["Abhi", "Gupta"]
raw_input("Please enter a string: ") in a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Can anyone please explain why it is not working in Python 2 and what is this "'bool' object is not callable" error as well?

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me with Python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 1):

For the python 3 example, `eval` isn't necessary since `input()` returns str.

As for the `TypeError` in python 2, you must've overrode `raw_input` to something type `bool` before that line. Ie. `raw_input = True` or something.

Comment: Actually, the `eval` is necessary (or something similar but safer, like `ast.literal_eval`), because the provided input included quote marks; without `eval`, it would have been checking `'"Abhi"' in ['Abhi', ...]` and the quotes would prevent it from finding the match. If the input didn't have quotes, then yeah, `input` alone works.

Comment: @ShadowRanger oh good catch! I guess I should say this to the OP: **Don't add quotation marks when inputting strings**